# Additional Checkout Attributes are not displayed on shipping method tab

Tags: shipping-methods

I use the following extension to include additional fields in my checkout process.

http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-additional-checkout-attributes-fields.html

However when I select the created custom field to be displayed on the shipping method screen, it is not displayed.

For shipping methods I use

```
- MSP_FlatShipping5 1.0.4 (stable) 
- Owebia Shipping 2
```

The support of FME says that both extensions are not supported by their plugin.

Does anybody know how I can ensure that the selected fields for shipping method are also displayed on this tab?